# Inactive Tasks Query in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

We are currently implementing Azure Devops for our backlog and task management. We are using a Kanban board setup. I would like to add a query to our dashboard to show Stale actions, effectively I want to see a list tasks that have been assigned but not modified in 7 days.
Initially I tried the state change date, but am finding that some tasks are having activity but just not a state change.
So I tried Changed Date, but that shows changes to the priority level when other items are changed.
How can I write a query that would only identify work items that have not been modified in over 7 days?

Comment: Hi Mike, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Comment: Hi Edward, logically this seems like it would work, but I have not had a chance to try yet. Thanks for the suggestion and I definitely will be trying and commenting back here.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the main issue here is that activity is on the 'tree' of work items and therefore deosn't represent a change in the item but other changes could be occurring on linked items? Would it follow that the Rules system having functionality to define rules based on related items would allow this to work fully? That itself is a very highly requested feature that to date seems to have been ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no existing field can meet your requirement. And the `Changed Date` field will be updated if there are any changes to this work item as you mentioned.

As a workaround, you could try following steps.

1. [Add a custom field to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops), I add field `LastEdit` which is Date/Time type and `IsActive` which is Text (single line) type for Task, and field `IsActive` is required, as below.
   [image]
2. [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops), I add 3 rules for Task, as below.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. Therefore, the field `LastEdit` is the last edit time, and users must edit the field `IsActive` when they update this work item and then the field `LastEdit` will be updated, otherwise they cannot save their changes.
4. Now you could filter target Tasks that using the field `LastEdit`, as below.
   [image]

Comment: I tired doing this a little differently, let me know if you see any glaring issues with it. I created the field "LastEdit" then a series of rules to update it. For example there is a rule for if the assignee is changed it updates the last edit field. And a rule if the description was changed, as well as an approval custom field. These rules copy the 'Changed Date' to 'LastEdit' when those fields are changed. Then I can query off of that date.    The shortcoming I see if there is no way to set a rule to update LastEdit based on a comment being entered

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I tried utilizing rules to set a "LastEdit" custom date field. I have 4 of these set for different changes, then I can query off the LastEdit date. It'll take a few days before I know if this works or not, but some simple testing seem ok. The major shortcoming I see is that I cant create a rule to update the LastEdit based on a new comment being entered.

Comment: This isnt quite working and I'm not sure why. I setup a couple rules to populate the "LastEdit" field, but sometimes it just doesnt do it. The one that seems to fail the most is when a new task is created from within another work item, it seems when you do that the rule to populate the "LastEdit" with the Last Change date just doesnt work.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could guide other community members who get the same issues, thank you.